# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: visitLocalDescendants called on an unattached node... What the issue is about?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I can't verify what the problem is isnce the exception does not include any codeline of my code:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: visitLocalDescendants called on an unattached node
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.shouldSharePointerInputWithSiblings(NodeCoordinator.java:1675)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:222)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:578)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:582)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hitInMinimumTouchTarget(HitTestResult.kt:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hit(HitTestResult.kt:97)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:582)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hitInMinimumTouchTarget(HitTestResult.kt:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hit(HitTestResult.kt:97)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:529)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:578)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:582)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hitInMinimumTouchTarget(HitTestResult.kt:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hit(HitTestResult.kt:97)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:529)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:578)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.access$hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:54)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:582)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$hit$1.invoke(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hitInMinimumTouchTarget(HitTestResult.kt:117)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.HitTestResult.hit(HitTestResult.kt:97)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hit-1hIXUjU(NodeCoordinator.kt:580)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:529)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:678)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator$Companion$PointerInputSource$1.childHitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.java:1225)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.hitTestChild-YqVAtuI(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:210)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.hitTest-YqVAtuI(NodeCoordinator.kt:526)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:951)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.hitTest-M_7yMNQ$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:944)
       at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.java:99)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1553)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1504)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1443)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3316)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2931)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3316)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2931)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3316)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2931)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3316)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2931)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:1109)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1971)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4388)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:1067)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:15803)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8153)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7877)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7213)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7270)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7236)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7434)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7244)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7491)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7217)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7270)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7236)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7244)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7217)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10788)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:10676)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10632)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10926)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:285)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Also, I don't know if the app crashed or not since that was reported by Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: I faced the same issue; did you get any additional info somehow?

Comment: @4face unfortunately, no.

Comment: I found this, don't know if related, but for me 1.6 alpha brought just a different exception :D

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303904810